# SQLServer transaction not working with PHP PDO using sqlsrv in command line

Tags: php, pdo, command-line, transactions, sqlsrv

I am using `SQLSRV` driver with `PDO` to connect `MSSQL Server` in Windows environment. This is quite weird issue that i am trying to run a cron job from command line like

[image]

I get fatal error saying `There is no active transaction` as soon as my db object tries to commit the transaction. Here is my source code

```
try {  
    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    INSERT STATEMENT 1
    INSERT STATEMENT 2
    ..................
    ..................
    $this->dbh->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->dbh->rollBack();
}
```

In order to check this whether transaction is working or not, i simply put `beginTransaction()` line in if condition like this

```
if ($this->dbh->beginTransaction()) {
    echo "Database transaction started";
else { 
    echo "Not started";
}
```

This is how pdo object look like when i print $this->dbh

```
PDO Object
(
)
```

Then control goes to else part and show `Not started`. The weird thing is that my cron file is located under my project which is consuming same database connection file that is used by other sections of the application (admin and front end). In the same cron file SELECT and UPDATE is working fine.

I observed that just single database instance is being created. Also database transaction is working fine for admin and front end area.

I could not get any help from Google to understand why database transaction is not working for command line execution.

Comment: show your connection object ($this->dbh)

Comment: I have updated my question by displaying how does pdo object look like. It look same at other area of application (admin and front end) where database transaction is working fine.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/pull/1307/files

Comment: have you tried to do the same but via native sqlsrv driver? ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) )

Comment: not yet. i can not do that as this is an existing application of client in which PDO is used. This application id developed in core php so which file from above link can be used to replace my sqlsrv extension file as i am not using Yii framework

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->dbh->beginTransaction();
try {  
    INSERT STATEMENT 1
    INSERT STATEMENT 2
    ..................
    ..................
    $this->dbh->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->dbh->rollBack();
}
```